# Angular2+ how to let child get notification from parent

Tags: angular

For Angular2+, we can use @output to notify parent, is there any way let child know which parent function is called before or after the Child event is emitted?

Below is the parent HTML code, which will call child component to execute onClick or OnClose function.

```
<child-comp (test1)="onClick()">
    ...
</child-comp>

<child-comp (test2)="onClose()">
    ...
</child-comp>
```

Below is the Child code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-comp'
})

export class ChildComponent{
    @Output() test1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() test2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    handleClick() {
        //this.test1.emit("test1 is emitted");
        //or 
        //this.test2.emit("test2 is emitted");

    }
}
```

The question is in both test1 and test2 are in handleClick function, once test1 or test2 event is emitted, how to let child know which parent function is executed?

Comment: You want to know if parent is subscribing to `test1` or `test2`? What is the problem you actually try to solve? You can just emit both and the parent decides which one it uses.

Comment: I guess you are confused with event emitters check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/inout)

Answer (score 0):

Add an @Input() property whatHappendInParent to the child and write something like this:

```
<child-comp (test1)="onClick()" [whatHappenedInParent] = whatHappened>
    ...
</child-comp>

<child-comp (test2)="onClose()" [whatHappenedInParent] = whatHappened>
    ...
</child-comp>
...
export class myParent {
  whatHappened: string;
  onClick(){
   this.whatHappened = "onClick was called";
  }
  onClose(){
   this.whatHappened = "onClose was called";
  }
}
```